# What would you call someone who follows their own path?

Tags: word-request

What would you call someone who follows their own path. One term I'm familiar with is conscious, but I want to know if their are any other words.

Comment: what do you mean by "follows their own path"? To me it means they live by their own standards, regardless of what others say." Conscious" to me means someone thinks a lot about things, is interested and informed. That is not the same, in my opinion.

Comment: [thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/freethinker) has a rather bizarre set of "synonyms" for ***freethinker*** (they have ***agnostic, atheist, infidel, libertine, skeptic***), but [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/freethinker) is more sensible: *character, codger, crackbrain, crackpot, crank, eccentric, freak, kook, nut, oddball, screwball, weirdo
bohemian, boho, counterculturist, deviant, enfant terrible, free spirit, heretic, iconoclast, individualist, loner, lone ranger, lone wolf, maverick, nonconformer, nonconformist
eight ball, misfit, outsider.*

Comment: Reggie - as pointed out, "conscious" doesn't have much to do with "following one's own path" (being independent?). You need to explain in more detail exactly what you're trying to express here.

Comment: As your example used the word 'conscious' perhaps you like the word [**aware**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/aware) although IMO this dictionary entry does not really do justice to the word. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aware) seems better.